# AdvancedFilter to exclude multiple criteria in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2019

I've been trying to use VBA's advanced filter method to **exclude** a set of criteria. Here is a simplified example.

[image]

My criteria are stored in the worksheet "Criteria", as such.

[image]

I now want to filter the data, such that any entry containing the name "Joe" OR the job "Pilot" are excluded.
I have tried the following:

```
Sub filter_data()
 With Worksheets("Data")
  .Activate
  .Range("A1:C10").AdvancedFilter _
  Action:= xlFilterInPlace, _
  CriteriaRange:= Worksheets("Criteria").Range("A1:C3")
 End With
End Sub
```

I checked if my code filters the data if I don't use the `<>` operator. This worked like a charm and  included only entries containing "Joe" OR "Pilot". However, excluding the said entries does not work. Can anybody help?

Comment: Your filter will INCLUDE all entries where Name is not Joe OR Job is not pilot. Is that what you want? If not, you need to express your filter criteria in terms of which rows you want to INCLUDE.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need. I want to include every entry that does not contain "Joe" OR "Pilot". Ultimately, I should be left with 5 entries and none of them contain the name "Joe" OR the job "Pilot". However, running my code like this filters nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for the negative you want AND not Or.

Then in A2 put: `<>Joe`

Then in C2 put: `<>Pilot`

So it looks like this:

[image]

Then change the reference to only the two rows:

```
Sub filter_data()

    With Worksheets("Data")
        .Range("A1:C10").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=Worksheets("Criteria").Range("A1:C2")
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. In my real data set, however; I also have cases where I want to exclude entries based on criteria 1 AND criteria 2. In this example, how do I exclude only entries where the name is "Joe" AND the job is "Doctor". Hence, only the entry in row 3 should be excluded. Is there also a clear differentiation between AND/ OR in the case where I use ```<>```?